# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: No Response Returned How to Fix

Tags: java, soap-client, wsdl2java

I have done a SOAP Client and I recive the next answer:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: no response returned.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.enviarFactura(Unknown Source)
    at bkon.facturas.clientsample.ClientSample.main(ClientSample.java:41)
```

I have generated the cliente with:
 wsdl2java -p bkon.facturas -verbose facturasspp2.wsdl

And I have tried with wsimport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using java 8, and spring boot it might be due to the dependency overridden,
You can get rid of this by adding the jaxws-rt dependency artifact

if you are using maven please add below on the pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>     
 </dependency>
```

if you are using gradle use below

```
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.1.4'
```